# sql file execution on oracle db is not giving any output

Tags: java, sql, oracle

my below snippet will connect to oracle database but not executing the sql file (containing list of queries on db)

i have a main class which accepts inputs related to database from the users and it calls the below class by passing the values .
below class will connect to db and then execute sql file provided by variable SQLPATH.

i am able to connect to db but its not executing the sql file on db.
can any one tell me where its going wrong .its not throwing any error .

below is the snippet

```
 public class SQLRunner {
        private static String driverName;
        //private static String con;
        private static Connection con;
        private static String url;
        private static String script_location = "";
        private static String file_extension = ".sql";
        private static ProcessBuilder processBuilder =null;


        public static void runSQLFile(String DBType, String userName, String password, String dbsid, String host, String port, String SQLFilePath) {
            System.out.println("invoked");
            if(DBType.equals("ORACLE")){
                url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+host+":"+port+":"+dbsid;
                System.out.println(url);

                driverName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";


            /*}else if(DBType.equals("DB2")){
                url = "jdbc:db2://"+host+":"+port+"/"+dbsid;
                driverName = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" ;

            }else if(DBType.equals("MSSQL")){
                url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+host+":"+port+";databaseName="+dbsid;
                driverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";


            }else{
                System.out.println("Database not supported@!");
            }*/


         try {
                Class.forName(driverName);
                try {
                   //System.out.println(url+"\n"+userName+"\n"+password);

                   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
                   System.out.println("DB connected");


               } catch (SQLException ex) {
                   // log an exception. fro example:
                   System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection."); 
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               // log an exception. for example:
                System.out.println("Driver not found."); 
          }



        }
            try {

                    script_location = "@" + SQLFilePath; //ORACLE
                    System.out.println(script_location);
                    processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sqlplus", userName+"/"+password+"@"+dbsid, script_location);
                    System.out.println("running sql");
                    //ORACLE
                    //script_location = "-i" + list_files[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    //  processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sqlplus", "-Udeep-Pdumbhead-Spc-de-deep\\sqlexpress-de_com",script_location);
                    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                    Process process = processBuilder.start();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    String currentLine = null;
                    while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(" "  + currentLine);
                    }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
     }

    }
```

Comment: You catch an exception without handle it. Do not do that.

Comment: What is it doing?  Is it raising an error?  If so, what error?  Off the top of my head, I'd expect at a minimum that you'd want a space between the `SID` and the call of the script `@createTables_Oracle.sql`.  Beyond that, you're going to have to do a bit of legwork to debug the problem.  Does it work if you use a fully qualified script file name?  If so, then the issue is that your code isn't seeing the path you expect.

Comment: sorry,it should take sql file value from scriptloaction just to check ,now i have edited the program please check and guide me where i am going wrong. when i run the program it says DB connected and print the scriptlocation as @d:\sqlfilename and halts

Comment: here i am using jdbc to connect to database

Comment: i have chnage dthe code to catch the exception ,i am getting below error i am getting below error now java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sqlplus": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified its taking scriptlocation as "@d:\script.sql" can anyone help me where the code is going wrong